# Angular2 barrel from same folder

Tags: angular

I create a barrel index.ts

```
    import { List } from './list';
    import { ListModule } from './list.module';
    import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
    import { ListCreateModule } from './create/list-create.module';
    import { ListCreateComponent } from './create/list-create.component';
    import { ListRoutingModule } from './list-routing.module';

export {
  List,
  ListModule,
  ListComponent,
  ListCreateModule,
  ListCreateComponent,
  ListRoutingModule,
};
```

I can import it this way:

```
import { List } from './list';
```

but if I am in folder list it does not work.

I tried:

```
import { List } from './index';
```

but I got an error

any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried to something like: import { List } from './';

Comment: Yes, I got an error unexpected value 'undefined' :-(

Comment: what error do you get exactly? I see no error in your code, so problem has to be elsewhere??

Comment: I got :
Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'ListModule'

Comment: I got :
Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'ListModule'

If I dot that:
import { List } from './list.component';
Then it works

Answer (score 0):

To export a module using barrel file (index.ts), you can use following code.

```
export * from './list';
export * from './list.module';
export * from './list.component';
export * from './create/list-create.module';
export * from './create/list-create.component';
export * from './list-routing.module';
```

And to import a module from same folder by using following;

```
import { List } from './';
```